# ¿Como actualizar un atributo personalizado en Active Directory?

Tags: script, powershell, windows-server, windows-server-2012, activedirectory

Hola chicos mi nombre es Bastián y soy estudiante.
vengo para pedir ayuda sobre un script de actualización de usuarios en active directory con archivo CSV.
cree las columnas en el esquema de active directory, todas aparecen en el perfil del usuario cuando los busco, pero cuando realizo la actualización el mensaje marca que el parámetro no existe.
Las actualizaciones mediante PowerShell de manera directa funciona y se ve reflejado, pero mediante el archivo CSV no encuentra las columnas, necesito su ayuda, para corregir mi error, les agradecería orientación

```
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory
    [String]$Ruta = Read-Host "Ingrese la ruta donde está el archivo csv (Por Ejemplo 
    C:\archivocsv.csv)"
    $ou="OU=DominioExtendido" + "," + (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName
    If(-Not(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter {Name -eq "DominioExtendido"})){New-ADOrganizationalUnit 
    "DominioExtendido" -Path (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName}
    $dominio=(Get-ADDomain).DNSRoot
    Import-Csv -Path $Ruta | foreach-object {
    $UPN = $_.Cuenta + "@" + "$dominio"
    New-ADUser -SamAccountName $_.Cuenta -UserPrincipalName $UPN -Name $_.Nombre -DisplayName 
    $_.Nombre -SurName $_.Apellidos -GivenName $_.Nombres -Description $_.Descripcion -Office 
    $_.Oficina -OfficePhone $_.Telefono -EmailAddress $_.Email -Title $_.Titulo -Department 
    $_.Departamento -Company $_.Compania -City $_.Ciudad -State $_.Region -AccountPassword 
    (ConvertTo- SecureString $_.Clave -AsPlainText -force) -Path $ou -Enabled $true - 
    ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Verbose -companyCode $_.CodigoEmpresa -companyID $._RutEmpresa - 
    socialReason $._razonSocial -acronymCountryCode $._CodigoPais -contractType $._TipoContrato - 
    businessUnity $._BU -officeLicence $._Licencia365}
    ""
    Write-Host La creacion de usuarios ha finalizado!!!
    ""
```

[image: Atributos en el perfil del usuario]
[image: Clase usuario con los atributos creados]
[image: Estructura Archivo CSV]

PS C:> ErrorTerminación(New-ADUser): "No se encuentra ningún parámetro que
coincida con el nombre del parámetro 'companyCode'."
New-ADUser : No se encuentra ningún parámetro que coincida con el nombre del
parámetro 'companyCode'.
En C:\Creacion_Masiva_Usuarios.ps1: 15 Carácter: 473+ ... $true -Verbose -
companyCode $_.Codigo_Empresa -companyID $._Rut_Empresa -socialR ...

- CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ADUser],
  ParameterBindingException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId :
  NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser

Comment: De nuevo (ya que al parecer eliminaste tu pregunta anterior): escribe los errores que arroja la consola _como texto, con formato_ ya que la imagen es prácticamente ilegible. Una [lectura recomendada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4773/156327) no está demás :)

Comment: Lo siento, ya que me decía que agregara imágenes, soy nuevo en este lugar, mejorare, añadiré los códigos de mi Log para que se visualice mejor